# Form States not working when compressed javascript is enabled

Tags: forms, javascript, 9

I have visible states setup for a 2 fields that correctly work when javascript aggregation is disabled. When I turn JS aggregation on both fields are visible no matter what option I select on the triggering field.

The error I see in the console is:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'drupalSettings.dialog.buttonClass = 'btn'') 
(anonymous function) — js_fsUR56avHuCdleLNsv7K8iPJi-p2GvAib4YZimyUwYM.js:2656
e — js_iZGsOOYcwKj6smZrna-ZUEcxHgdurhEAEKqi_VGeytE.js:1399
(anonymous function) — js_iZGsOOYcwKj6smZrna-ZUEcxHgdurhEAEKqi_VGeytE.js:1407
undefined
```

The exact line causing this is:

```
 // Create the "modal" plugin bridge.
        Bootstrap.Modal.Bridge = function() {
            var Modal = this;
```

however I didn't write that line and can't seem to find it.

EDIT:
These are the errors I get with JS aggregation disabled:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Bootstrap.Modal')
    (anonymous function) (modal.jquery.ui.bridge.js:73)
    (anonymous function) (drupal.bootstrap.js:239)
    (anonymous function) (modal.jquery.ui.bridge.js:17)
    Global Code (modal.jquery.ui.bridge.js:585)
```

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.DEFAULTS')
    (anonymous function) (drupal.js:14)
```

I'm not using any custom javascript on this page just relying purely on Drupals Form API and '#states'.

EDIT 2: Turning off "Enable Bootstrap Modals" in the themes appearance settings menu allows the states to continue working. The theme is not using a CDN(both options error out for some reason) and I'm not sure why the local compile isn't working.

Comment: It is helpful to disable aggregation when getting console stack traces.

Comment: Looks like bootstrap JS is not loading/loaded.

Comment: I think you're right but I'm not sure how to fix it. disabling Modals in the bootstrap theme settings lets it work but also stops modals.